# When trying to installing Pods I get the error "with_indifferent_access"

Tags: cocoapods

When I made pod install on terminal this problem appeared.

cocoapods-core-1.7.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize': undefined method`with_indifferent_access' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: Please show the podfile content here

Comment: Try `$ [sudo] gem update cocoapods`

Answer (score 10):

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/
```

Try this command.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Life-saving command 

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it really worked well,
Executing the command

> rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/

and running

> pod install